# eclipse CDT source code parser misfunctioned?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have this code:

```
void AlgoEvaluation::init(const char * filename)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    int n;
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &n);
    int case_num;
    double weight, arcgis_time;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        fscanf(fp, "%d%lf%lf", &case_num, &weight, &arcgis_time);
    }
}
```

The code in Eclipse CDT editor have underlined tilde at `fopen` and `fscanf` , and **Function 'fopen' could not be resolved** when I put mouse cursor to it.

There should be nothing wrong with the the code, but I wonder why Eclipse gives the above information, which is disturbing and misleading. I'am not familiar with Eclipse CDT settings, How could I solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you include `stdio.h` in your code? `fopen` and `fscanf` are defined in that header.

Comment: @urish Yes, included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out that the problem is The `Toolchains` options when create a new project using CDT.

With the `Toolchains` options(Cross GCC, MSVC), I choose Cross GCC while on My windows this is no gcc installed! So the choice should be MSVC, cause MSVC is installed with Visual Studio.

After MSVC choice, the problem parsing C standard library is solved.